# Make ViewPager forget current item position upon data change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` that holds, say, three `Fragment`s. The `Fragments` are A (position 0) , B, and C (position 2). `Fragment B` is currently visible.

Upon user interaction, I will call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, and there are now five `Fragments`. They are D (position 0), E, F, G and H (position 4).

The current behaviour is that `Fragment E` is shown by default after the data changes. (The `ViewPager` stays at its previous position.) However, I would like the `ViewPager` to show the `position-0` item each time `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` gets some new data.

I have tried `setCurrentItem(0)` on the `ViewPager`. But `Fragment E` is still shown before the `ViewPager` scrolls to `Fragment D`.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setCurrentItem(0, false)` instead

**Edit:**

> public void setCurrentItem (int item, boolean smoothScroll)

false to disable smoothScroll

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int,%20boolean%29

Comment: However, what if I just want the `ViewPager` to show the zeroth page right away without any scroll? I thought I saw something like `setPrimaryItem()`

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake about setPrimaryitem(). You should use  `setCurrentItem(0, false)` not `setCurrentItem(0)`

`public void setCurrentItem (int item, boolean smoothScroll)`, false means no smoothScroll

Comment: But there  is still some kind of scroll going on? Can i just show the zeroth item right away?

Comment: you tried and you see scroll? it should have no scroll effect

Comment: When `smoothScroll` is true, I see scroll effect. When it is false, I see no scroll effect. It achieves my desired effect. But I presume there is still some "transition" going on, which does not sound very efficient to me.

Comment: `smoothScroll  True to smoothly scroll to the new item, false to transition immediately`, there is "transition" but no animation. This is how ViewPager works, by transition, only means it clear any cache and redraw the new one, I dunno how you make it "more efficient", maybe you have to create your own ViewPager.

Comment: I was just thinking that if there was a "transition" from Y to X, then Y must be created somehow. Thanks. I think `smoothScroll = false` satisfies my need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88442/discussion-between-derek-fung-and-jonas).